# What does "list = [1] + [0] * n" do

Tags: python-3.x, list

I've come across the code of a classmate and the first line of his method drew my attention. I know it's about a list, but I don't really know what it does and he can't remember (he didn't leave any comments in the code).

```
def foo(n, k):
        blah = [1] + [0] * n
        for i in range (1, n + 1):
                for j in range (i, n + 1)
                        blah[j] += blah[j - 1]
        return blah[n]
```

Comment: What's preventing you from running the line by itself with random n values?

Comment: Where is the second parameter (`k`) being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplication happens before addition

For an `int n`, `[0] * n` returns a list, with size of `n`, all of `0`

Adding two lists together will concatenate them

So that line returns something like `[1, 0,0,0]` for `n=3`